# Texturing a quad (triangle strip) OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I got 256*256 texture and everything is fine, but part i trying to map whole texture on whole quad is ruined.
My quad textured only by 1/5 from left to right, rest is black which means no texturing there.
Texturing part in general is working like it shoud.
**glFrontFace** is untouched (default)
Texture created with:
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

```
GLfloat quad_pos[] =
{
 0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
-0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
 0.5,-0.5, 0.0,
-0.5,-0.5, 0.0
};

//Maybe i need 5 and 6 verticles tex coords?
GLfloat quad_tex[]=
{
0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 1.0,
1.0, 0.0
};

GLfloat quad_col[]=
{
0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
};

 //In draw_quad method()
//Binding texture and setting uniforms/attributes skipped
```

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 av_col;
attribute vec4 av_pos;
attribute vec2 av_tex;
varying vec4 vv_col;
varying vec2 vv_tex;
uniform mat4 um_mvp;
void main()
{
 vv_col = av_col;
 vv_tex = av_tex;
 gl_Position = um_mvp * av_pos; 
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision lowp float;
uniform sampler2D us_tex;
varying vec4 vv_col;
varying vec2 vv_tex;
void main()
{
gl_FragColor = (vv_col * texture2D(us_tex, vv_tex));
}
```

if change tex coords to

```
GLfloat quad_tex[]=
{
0.0, 0.2,
0.0, 0.0,
0.2, 0.2,
0.2, 0.0
};
```

Quad will be fully textured and colored, but texture will be overscaled (minecraft pixel style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quad will be fully textured and colored, but texture will be overscaled (minecraft pixel style)

It sounds as though you have default `GL_NEAREST` filtering enabled. Try using `GL_LINEAR` instead:

```c
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml